# spring.datasource.password from system property not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I used to complete sample from [Spring Data](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa)...

It works well.

I added application.properties

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./h2/demo
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=wrong
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I worked (apparently on first run it creates the database with whatever password defined).

When I changed the password to `newWrong` it started failing as expected (so I verified it's checking password).

Now I changed the property file to contain

```
spring.datasource.password=#{systemProperties['pass']}
```

and I changed the `AccessingDataJpaApplication`'s main to:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("pass", "wrong" );
    SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
}
```

and it is not working - still complaining about the password.

On the other hand, when I added

```
@Value("${bar}")
String foo;
```

and defined in application properties (and used `wrong` for password to prevent failing)

```
bar=#{systemProperties['pass']}
```

this statement in Application class

```
System.out.println("foo: " + foo);
```

prints `foo: wrong`.

Why the same is not working for `spring.datasource.password` property?

Comment: How you call `spring.datasource.password` ?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the exact answer to your question, but I believe it is the answer to what you are trying to solve.

You can simply pass the password to the app when you launch it on the command line by appending a `-Dspring.datasource.password=wrong` to the command. You can do that with any spring property.

If you are running from and IDE, you can edit the run configuration, there should be a field for *VM Options* where you can pass that in.

That would be the canonical way of handling in Spring.

Comment: While it works, passing passwords by command line might not be the best option, security-wise...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line or change the path(example /h2/demo1).

> `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./h2/demo`

because  the last configuration is storage on this file.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with

```
spring.datasource.password=${pass}
```

and it works correctly.

You can also use environment variables of format SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD to define these properties. Spring Boot will resolve them without any addition to application configuration.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files